# Design in ERD and export XML files for metadata

Tags: xml, xsd, uml, entity-relationship, erd

In order to isolate data model changes from the database schema (and resulting schema changes), i've implemented a metadata model the uses XML files to describe the underlying scientific data being stored in other tables.  I'm looking for a design tool that would support defining this metadata in and ERD format that could then allow grouping of related entities into XML files of name-value pairs and define the key relationships across XML files extracted from the hierarchical parent-child relationships defined in the ERD.  I've used Visio, ERWin and Popkin System Architect in the past, but this was sometime ago and at the time, this wasn't the problem that I was exploring.  Are there tools that support ERD to XML (and related DTD and possibly XSL files too) design model?  I know I can export the SQL commands to create a native database schema, but not sure if anything exists that creates XML?

Answer (score 0):

One tool that is very helpful for me is ER/Studio Data Architect.  It allows you to reverse engineer an existing database, make changes to both the logical and physical models, and does support exporting as an XML schema.

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio-data-architect

There are about a million features in the product which mean it is both a bit challenging to pick up and use right away and also there is a significant price tag I believe.